Unnecessary re-rendering of unaffected components in a hierarchical tree structure
I'm implementing a TreeView component in React to display a hierarchical file structure. Each node can be expanded or collapsed. I first went with local state but I needed a feature to expand all/collapse all so I had to lift the state up.
However, I've run into a performance issue: expanding or collapsing one node triggers unnecessary re-renders of all nodes, even though they does not need to.
Here’s a simplified version of my component:
import { useState } from "react";

export default function TreeView({ data }) {
  const [expandedNodes, setExpandedNodes] = useState(new Set());

  const toggleNode = (nodeId) => {
    setExpandedNodes((prev) => {
      const next = new Set(prev);
      if (next.has(nodeId)) next.delete(nodeId);
      else next.add(nodeId);
      return next;
    });
  };

  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map((node) => (
        <TreeNode
          key={node.id}
          node={node}
          expandedNodes={expandedNodes}
          isExpanded={expandedNodes.has(node.id)}
          onToggle={toggleNode}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

function TreeNode({ node, isExpanded, onToggle, expandedNodes }) {
  return (
    <li>
      <div onClick={() => onToggle(node.id)}>
        {node.name} {isExpanded ? "[-]" : "[+]"}
      </div>
      <ul>
        {isExpanded &&
          node.children &&
          node.children.map((n) => (
            <TreeNode
              key={n.id}
              node={n}
              isExpanded={expandedNodes.has(n.id)}
              expandedNodes={expandedNodes}
              onToggle={onToggle}
            />
          ))}
      </ul>
    </li>
  );
}

Root
├── Documents
└── Pictures
    ├── Vacation
    └── Work

The problem is that when I expand the "Pictures" folder, for example, the "Documents" folder also re-renders, even though it technically does not need to as it is unaffected by the update
I've tried to memoize everything but the expandedNodes state is always new, making  the whole Tree to re-render on every update.
Link to sandbox https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/angry-golick-fpyt52

"I've tried to memoize everything but the expandedNodes state is always new, making the whole Tree to re-render on every update." - It seems you understand why the other tree nodes rerender then. You are passing down props that change.

The only solution I can see is to modify the state before passing it down and serialise it as a string so that react can compare it by value, but this seems like such an effort that I'm wondering if I'm doing it wrong or missing out on a potentially better way of doing this.

I considered a React Context for holding the state and handler, but that sill has the same fundamental issue of triggering component rerenders since the root node component is wrapped in the provider and as such the entire ReactTree is rerendered. It seems every node needs the entire expandedNodes state to derive each node's expanded "state". Is there any actual issue or problem you have in the code you are using?

My Collapse component comes from a design system and is not optimised for re-renders at all, I see significant fps drops when I have more than 500 nodes, which is the low bar for my use case. Maybe I should virtualise the tree view, but I'm not sure how to go about it as the height is variable.

You’ll need to make the state that tracks expanded nodes also have the same tree shape rather than using a flat set. This way you can only pass each subtree the state for that subtree.

I played with this also and failed but as I see it, it would require much effort to make this work for large datasets. In this particular case I would use a open source alternative like this one: https://github.com/diogofcunha/react-virtualized-tree.
